# How do i prase the below simple JsonObject in swift 4 ? I need the value of code and message

Tags: json, swift

//This is the json Response where i need to parse.

// I need the below code value for condition.

```
 {
   Code = 0;
   Message = "Login Fail";
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask], [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hi Gary, from the structure you posted in your question, it appears to be invalid JSON.  Valid JSON does not have line endings terminated with semi colons.  Swift also does not have semi colon terminated key:value pairs (dictionary) either so I'm not exactly sure what data structure this is you are getting back from the server.

Answer (score 1):

#### Forward, the original data structure posted does not conform and is not a JSON return object

```
{
  Code = 0;
  Message = "Login Fail";
}
```

#### Converted to JSON

```
{
 "Code" : 0,
 "Message" : "Login Fail"
}
```

with this Swift 4 has a very nice protocol called `Decodable` and `JSONDecoder`.  These are new to `Foundation`.

#### Step 1 : Create either a struct or class that conforms to Decodable

```
struct ErrorResponse: Decodable {
   var code: String?
   var message: String?
   enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
       case code = "Code"
       case message = "Message"
   }
}
```

**Alternative Declaration Not Using Optionals**

```
struct ErrorResponse: Decodable {
   var code: String
   var message: String
   enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
       case code = "Code"
       case message = "Message"
   }
}
```

Apple also provides many examples of the proper use of `Decodable` and `CodingKey` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

**Notice**: how using `CodingKeys` here to denote that properties that are lower cased but what is received from the server is uppercased.  You can use `CodingKey` to encode and decode properties to your own naming convention.

#### Step 2: Use a JSONDecoder

```
guard let responseError = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ErrorResponse.self, from: data) else {
  print("Error: Could not parse JSON")
  return
}
print("code: \(responseError.code)")
print("message: \(responseError.message)")
```

Comment: //Hi thanks for your answer but i am getting response in below format

Comment: code: Optional("0")
message: Optional("Login Fail")

Comment: I may need the values for condition check like 0 and 1

Comment: yes this is correct.  Both "code" and "message" are defined as "Optional" types.  Swift supports Optional types which is one of its very powerful features.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the usage and non-usage declaration of optionals since Optionals can be confusing for newcomers to the Swift language.  However, I encourage anyone who is not familiar with optionals to read up on this powerful feature in Swift. I would personally start [at the source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional)

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can use [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) swift library for easily converting object models to and from JSON :

**To break it down :**

1. Add ObjectMapper library to your project using CocoaPods :

   ```
       pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 3.3'
   ```
2. Define new class or struct (Model) that implements the Mappable protocol noting that you must conform to the Mappable protocol by implementing his two methods :

   ```
   class Response: Mappable {

       var code: Int?
       var message: String?

       required init?(map: Map) { }

        // Mappable
       func mapping(map: Map) {
          code            <- map["code"]
          message         <- map["message"]
       }
     }
   ```
3. Parse the API response and convert Dictionary response to Response Model Object :

   ```
   if let data = resultDictionary["response"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                  let  response = Mapper<Response>().map(JSONObject: data)

                   print("code = \(response.code)")
                   print("message = \(response.message.)")
      }
    }
   ```

response model is mappable object contains the code & message.

Comment: Why use ObjectMapper when you could use the built in `Decodable` protocol?

Comment: I think the Object Mapper more easier and straightforward for parsing JSON response . but surely in more advance levels we could move on the Codable Protocol . thanks @AshleyMills